# How to create an astrology chart in Python from planetary data (derived from a custom algorithm) that dynamically updates with user input?

Tags: python, graphics, visualization

Using my algorithm, I can take space-time data as an input list & generate accurate planetary & astrological data as a 2D lists as follows:

```
Input_list: [Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude]
Input_sample: [1990, 4, 9, 21, 12, 30, 22.51361111111111, 88.3411111111111, 9.14]
```

Output:2 2D lists "**GRAHA POSITIONS**" & "**HOUSE CUSPS**"

```
--------------------GRAHA POSITIONS-----------------------------
[Planet, Z.sign, degree, minute, second, nakshatra, pada, angle_in_float]
['Sun', 'Aries', 19, 30, 30, 'Revati', 4, 19.508579713622044]
['Moon', 'Libra', 14, 36, 20, 'Chitra', 1, 14.60574883925213]
['Mercury', 'Taurus', 8, 14, 2, 'Bharani', 2, 8.23414995759422]
['Venus', 'Pisces', 3, 21, 55, 'Shatavishak', 2, 3.3653055864194243]
['Mars', 'Aquarius', 21, 33, 43, 'Dhanistha', 3, 21.562001016537806]
['Jupiter', 'Cancer', 3, 45, 55, 'Ardra', 3, 3.765369522224674]
['Saturn', 'Capricorn', 24, 49, 1, 'U.Ashadha', 3, 24.81699905482151]
['Rahu', 'Aquarius', 14, 21, 35, 'Dhanistha', 1, 14.359770567077646]
['Ketu', 'Leo', 14, 21, 35, 'Ashlesha', 3, 14.359770567077646]
----------------------HOUSE CUSPS-------------------------------
[Cusp, Z.sign, degree, minute, second, nakshatra, pada, angle_in_float]
[1, 'Scorpio', 29, 16, 11, 'Anuradha', 2, 29.269861999821757]
[2, 'Sagittarius', 28, 55, 44, 'Moola', 3, 28.929165427870714]
[3, 'Aquarius', 0, 37, 54, 'Sravana', 1, 0.6317628121900043]
[4, 'Pisces', 3, 49, 57, 'Shatavishak', 3, 3.8325043513459605]
[5, 'Aries', 5, 53, 38, 'U.Bhadrapada', 4, 5.893938324894634]
[6, 'Taurus', 4, 20, 36, 'Bharani', 1, 4.343341833871818]
[7, 'Taurus', 29, 16, 11, 'Krittika', 4, 29.269861999821728]
[8, 'Gemini', 28, 55, 44, 'Ardra', 1, 28.929165427870714]
[9, 'Leo', 0, 37, 54, 'Pushya', 3, 0.6317628121900043]
[10, 'Virgo', 3, 49, 57, 'P.Phalguni', 1, 3.832504351345932]
[11, 'Libra', 5, 53, 38, 'Hasta', 2, 5.893938324894634]
[12, 'Scorpio', 4, 20, 36, 'Svati', 3, 4.34334183387179]
```

Now I want to use this data to create visualizations as as South Indian horoscope chart. I've added an example chart to show what I want to achieve.[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsXOY.jpg)

In the image, the chart background with zodiac symbols in the bottom right is static, I can simply use an image for that. The planets & asc symbol i.e. **HOUSE CUSPS [0][0]** (red slanted line in Scorpio) are vectors, which I'd like to import into my program & assign to planet names i.e. **GRAHA POSITIONS[i][0]** from the above 2D list.

The number above a planet is its angle in the rashi i.e. **GRAHA POSITIONS[i][2,3,4]** & the text below is its Nakshatra & pada i.e. **GRAHA POSITIONS[i][5,6]**.

The little black numbers in the bottom left of a rashi are the cusps in that rashi i.e. **HOUSE CUSPS[i][0]**.

Is it reasonable to try to build this idea in Python? If yes, then how? If no, then please guide me.

I'm an amateur programmer by need, with only few months of experience in Python. I'm very eager to build this software for research in statistical astrology aimed to predict natural calamities decades ahead & at a fraction of the current cost.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you help me with the algo for getting above data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can most certainly do this in Python and I would suggest looking into [Pillow/PIL](https://python-pillow.org/). Basically you need to look at this as more of image manipulation rather than a chart/graph. You start with a basic background image and add all details on top of it.

Just out of curiosity, how are you generating the planetary & astrological data?

Comment: one can calculate planetary longitudes with pyswisseph. refer the documentation https://astrorigin.com/pyswisseph/sphinx/index.html